# How to extract from a .nc file based on a shapefile in R?

Tags: r, spatial, raster, shapefile, extract

I have a .nc file which has global data and I want to extract the data which are within the boundary of a .shp file. I have tried several methods, but still have some problems.

The .nc file can be downloaded at https://www.dropbox.com/s/0ba6v4fnck8wjdm/spei03.nc?dl=0 and the .shp file can be downloaded at https://www.dropbox.com/s/8wfgf8207dbh79r/gpr_000b11a_e.zip?dl=0

```
library(rgdal)
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

shpfile<-readOGR("gpr_000b11a_e.shp", layer="gpr_000b11a_e")
g <- spTransform(shpfile, CRS("+proj=aea +lat_1=50 +lat_2=70 +lat_0=40 +lon_0=-96 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=NAD83 +units=m +no_defs +ellps=GRS80 +towgs84=0,0,0"))
ncdata = raster(x="spei03.nc",varname="spei")
proj4string(ncdata) = proj4string(g)
Mydata = rasterToPoints(mask(x=ncdata,mask = g))
```

But then I cannot get any data. Thanks for any help.

Comment: I downloaded your .nc file and has no values. Check `summary(values(ncdata))`, the numnes of `NA's` is equal to `ncell(ncdata)`

Comment: Yes, that is one of the problems. If you use `spei_nc=nc_open("spei03.nc")` and `spei03 <- ncvar_get(spei_nc, varid="spei")`, you will see the values. By the way, the first two time steps of the .nc file contain only NA values. If you look the third time step, it will have correct values.

Answer (score 1):

To extract values, use `extract()` function. But, you need to select what time step you want to use:

```r
library(ncdf4)
library(raster)

shpfile<-shapefile("gpr_000b11a_e.shp") # load shapefile

spei_nc=nc_open("spei03.nc") # open .nc data
mtrx <- ncvar_get(spei_nc, varid="spei")[,,3] # extact value. In this case, 3 is for time step number 3

spei_r <- raster(t(mtrx),xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90) # create a raster with data (it is flipped)
spei_r <- flip(spei_r,2) # correct raster
projection(spei_r) <- '+proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +ellps=WGS84 +towgs84=0,0,0 ' # add CRS

plot(spei_r) # check result
```

[image]

```r
# reproject shapefile
g <- spTransform(shpfile, spei_r@crs)

# extract values by ecah feature
spei_values <- extract(spei_r,g)

# extract mean by each feature
spei_mean <- extract(spei_r,g,fun=mean,na.rm=T)

spei_mean
##              [,1]
##  [1,] -0.37517873
##  [2,]  0.24568238
##  [3,]  0.12212451
##  [4,] -1.44496705
##  [5,]  0.57723304
##  [6,]  0.08963697
##  [7,]  0.07029936
##  [8,]  0.01176584
##  [9,]  0.35061048
## [10,]  0.09197929
## [11,]  0.41005611
## [12,]  0.19130312
## [13,] -0.69751740
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply and your code works great. But I still have some questions: First, in your code `spei_r <- raster(t(mtrx),xmn=-180, xmx=180, ymn=-90, ymx=90) # create a raster with data (it is flipped)`
and `spei_r <- flip(spei_r,2) # correct raster` why do you use `t(mtrx)` and then `flip` the matrix?   Second, for your result `spei_values`, I wonder how to find the corresponding longitude and latitude for all spei values? Thanks a lot.

Comment: @YangYang the first part is because the matrix has a weird order, but with `t(); flip()` the problem is solved. Second, use `spei_values <- as.data.frame(mask(spei_r, g), xy = T)`

Comment: Thank you so much for your explanation. However, when I try `spei_values <- as.data.frame(mask(spei_r, g), xy = T)`, the result contains only longitude and latitude, without any spei values. Could you fix this? Thanks a lot.